# why am I getting AssertionError: train: No labels found in /content/dataset/test/labels.cache, can not start training

Tags: deep-learning, detection, yolo, yolov5

AssertionError: train: No labels found in /content/dataset/test/labels.cache, can not start training
[Automatically generated cache files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvk7F.png)

I'm doing yolo5
An error occurs during the configuration and training a dataset.

I understand that the command automatically creates a cache file under the train folder. I've confirmed that it's actually made
These errors appear. What's the problem? I ask for your help me.

An error occurs when only the dataset is different from the same code

Comment: Probably it is the path problem in config in the `data/your_custom_data.yaml`. It has to work if you follow [this ](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/Train-Custom-Data)

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same error, I have created a folder named "labels" inside that two subfolders names train and val where the labels of all the files are placed.

[image: labels folder]

[image: subfolders]

[image: train]

[image: val]

Yolov5 automatically checks the labels folder where all the labels for the train and val images are there or not if it's not present then it throws this error. Please maintain the directory structure to resolve this issue.

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Thanks!!!